# Record the voice call packets in a file

Tags: android

I want to make an app to record voice call. I have read many relevant articles about it. I am aware that latest Galaxy comes with this feature. But wanted to know a few things:

1. When we use the native AudioRecord::start(), where is the recorded data stored in the File System?
2. What is the format of the recorded data?
3. how to access that data to manipulate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make an app to record voice call.

That is not possible in Android, as SDK applications do not have access to the in-call audio stream.

> I am aware that latest Galaxy comes with this feature.

This was implemented by the device manufacturer in firmware. If you create your own custom firmware, this may be possible.

> When we use the native AudioRecord::start(), where is the recorded data stored in the File System?

It does not store "recorded data" "in the File System". You get `byte[]` of data -- it is up to you to do something with it.

> What is the format of the recorded data?

8-bit or 16-bit PCM, as you request via the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But I doubt one statement ==It does not store "recorded data" "in the File System". You get byte[] of data -- it is up to you to do something with it.== I think it doesnot return any byte[] data, it records and stores in some file.. If it would be returning the Incall Audio stream, then the problem is solved because I need the stream data.Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: @user569785: "I think it doesnot return any byte[] data, it records and stores in some file" -- no, `AudioRecord` does not: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html